# PFRelation won't save, trying to link message object to PFUser object

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, pfuser, pfrelation

I am having trouble saving a PFRelation in Parse. I have a message PFObject and want to add this to a PFRelation receivedMessages in the PFUser class. Code is below. Everything works up to    actually trying to create the relationship. I have set the user object fine, NSLog displays the correct user but it appears **[sendtoUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)** is not being called at all as "relation saved" is not displayed in the console. Could someone help please? Thanks

```
PFObject *message = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@“message”];
message[@“fromUser"]=[PFUser currentUser].username;
message[@“message"]=@"喵!";
message[@“read"]=@NO;

[message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@“message saved”);
    PFQuery *usernameQuery = [PFUser query];
    [usernameQuery whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[[self.friends objectAtIndex:index] username]];
    [usernameQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        PFUser *sendtoUser = (PFUser *)objects[0];
        NSLog(@"send to user: %@", sendtoUser.username); //this works

        PFRelation *receivedMessages = [sendtoUser relationForKey:@"receivedMessages”];
        [receivedMessages addObject:message];

        [sendtoUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@“relation saved”); //this doesn’t display at all                
        }];//end save user relation block

    }];//end username query block


}];//end save message block, this works
```

Comment: I also checked the PFRelation with NSLog("%@".receivedMessages); and all seems in order. It's just that final line when I try to save it, I can't figure out for the life of me why it won't work.

Comment: what is (PFUser *)objects[0] returning?

Comment: also is `equalTo:[[self.friends objectAtIndex:index] username]]` valid? usually index isn't a valid indexPath unless you've named an NSIndexPath index?

Comment: I figured it out, you cannot modify another PFUsers fields, you can only modify your own. Had to solve it by creating two new classes, messages and messageBank. The message bank is linked to the PFUser and message bank has a PFRelation to messages. Can save info that way. thanks

Comment: this is true - pointers are the key to successfully cross-referencing in Parse